# Remove emphasized spaces on lstlisting with bash

Tags: spacing, listings

I have the following code that prints my bash code on the document

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, caption=Comandi per l'installazione dell'engine di Docker,captionpos=b]
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
$ echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
\end{lstlisting}
```

I have added some settings for the listings so, when the page ends it automatically breaks the line

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}
```

Now, the main issue is that, for some reason, the output emphasized the spaces, but only inside the "" symbols (see image below)

[image]

How do I remove the emphasized spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the effect of `listings` option `showstringspaces=true`, which is set by default. You can add `showstringspaces=false` to cancel/revert that.